# Change/specify the dark color, so unlit areas have a specific color

Tags: three.js

Is there a simple way in three.js to specify a color for "dark"? That is, in a scene with light, the colors of an object fade to black. What I want is for them to fade to a different color. I want to specify what color "unlit" is.  I'm using a MeshPhongMaterial in this particular case.

---

Answer: There is no way to do this in the current three.js version. I've selected an answer with possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called ambient light.

```
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
```

The argument to the constructor is the color of the light.

When using `MeshPhongMaterial`, it is also advisable to set the *ambient reflectance of the material* to match the material's *diffuse reflectance*, also know as the `color`.

```
material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
material.ambient.set( 0xff0000 );
```

If you follow this advice, your scene should look pretty good.

three.js r.64

Comment: I am using Ambient light, but it doesn't really do what I want here. It adds to the existing color, and it can also be dimmed (at least on a shiny Phong material). It's more like I want a particular color to be the "minimum" color on the material.

Comment: If you want a "minimum" color without regard to the lights in the scene, you can specify `material.emissive`, which makes an object "glow". Everything is additive, so it will affect the color of the faces that are lit, too. Setting any of the lights to have a color other than white also gives you some flexibility. You can also write your own `ShaderMaterial` and achieve anything you want.